# How to exit a loop with Boolean variables in tKinter

Tags: python, tkinter

What i am trying to do is start a function after I press the Start button and be able to stop it while it is looping with the press of the Stop button with Boolean variables and an if statement. I cannot figure out how to make it work.

```
from tkinter import *

def listen():
    if running==True:
        print("running")
def startCommand():
    global running
    running=True
def stopCommand():
    global running
    running=False
    print("stop")


running=True

root = Tk()
root.geometry("200x100")

startButton=Button(root, text="Start", command=startCommand)    
startButton.pack()
exitButton=Button(root, text="Stop", command=stopCommand)
exitButton.pack()

root.after(100, listen)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Should the function be able to be restarted? In other words, should the state of the function be preserved after stopping, such that you can press `start` again and have it resume where it left off?

Answer (score 1):

It is a simple fix, it is that `.after` schedules a function to run only once (after the set amount of milliseconds):

```py
def listen():
    if running:
        print("running")
    root.after(100, listen)
```

So you reschedule the function to run again in the function itself too, if you want it to loop.

Btw, `if variable == True:` is the same as `if variable:` (also if `variable` is some other object it will too evaluate to True) and `if variable == False` is the same as `if not variable:` (tho `if not variable:` will also get executed if variable is an empty string (`""`) or integer `0` or `None` or `False`)

Also:
I strongly advise against using wildcard (`*`) when importing something, You should either import what You need, e.g. `from module import Class1, func_1, var_2` and so on or import the whole module: `import module` then You can also use an alias: `import module as md` or sth like that, the point is that don't import everything unless You actually know what You are doing; name clashes are the issue.

I strongly suggest following [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). Function and variable names should be in `snake_case`, class names in `CapitalCase`. Don't have space around `=` if it is used as a part of keyword argument (`func(arg='value')`) but have space around `=` if it is used for assigning a value (`variable = 'some value'`). Have space around operators (`+-/` etc.: `value = x + y`(except here `value += x + y`)). Have two blank lines around function and class declarations.

Comment: thank you very much for the help and the reference material. Much appreciated